# Mule - Inject flow or session variable into Spring bean

Tags: mule

I am trying to pass a variable to a Spring bean like so:

```
<component doc:name="Java">
            <no-arguments-entry-point-resolver />
            <prototype-object class="org.test.MyComponent">
                <property key="fileName" value="#[sessionVars.filename]" />
            </prototype-object>
        </component>
```

But the expression never resolves? Is there a another way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a confusion with the spring configuration and Mule Expression language(MEL).

Point 1:
Even though the component is defined inside the Mule Config file. The elements (tags) `<property/>`  is from the Springs Bean schema definition. So the attribute values of `key` and `value` are not interpreted by the MEL.

Point 2: As it is provided as setter injection which is invoked during loading(instantiation) the value of session variable(run time value) will not be available.

One possible solution to this would be to make the component implement Callable interface of Mule. So that you will have access to the MuleMessage which contains the session variable.

```
@Override
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {          
    MuleMessage muleMessage = eventContext.getMessage();
    muleMessage.getProperty("propertyName", PropertyScope.SESSION);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

When the Mule server starts, each of the  elements are loaded, and the `component` and `spring-object` are created. I don't think you can pass session variable or for that matter any variable other than `context-properties` to object creation happening at server start-up time.